# image url shown where image should be

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a board game and when the user clicks on one of the boxes, it flips over and shows the letter. I wanted to instead have an image displayed when the user clicks instead of a letter. I have an `array` that holds all of the letters but when replaced with a `imageurl`, it just shows the `url` instead of the image. I will paste the `html,css and js` down below.

#### js

```
var memory_array = ["./naruto.gif ", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;
Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function() {
  var i = this.length,
    j,
    temp;
  while (--i > 0) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = this[j];
    this[j] = this[i];
    this[i] = temp;
  }
};
function newBoard() {
  tiles_flipped = 0;
  var output = "";
  memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
  for (var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++) {
    output +=
      '<div id="tile_' +
      i +
      '" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\'' +
      memory_array[i] +
      "')\"></div>";
  }
  document.getElementById("memory_board").innerHTML = output;
}
function memoryFlipTile(tile, val) {
  //if the title is empty and array = 0  then the rest of code will perform
  if (tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2) {
    //the tile selected will have a white background and the val will be produced
    tile.style.background = "#FFF";
    tile.innerHTML = val;
    //if the  array equal = 0
    if (memory_values.length == 0) {
      //push the val and the title id to their respective arrays
      memory_values.push(val);
      memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
      //if the  array equal = 1
    } else if (memory_values.length == 1) {
      //push the val and the title id to their respective arrays
      memory_values.push(val);
      memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
      //if memory_values values are the same
      if (memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]) {
        tiles_flipped += 2;
        // Clear both arrays
        memory_values = [];
        memory_tile_ids = [];
        // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
        if (tiles_flipped == memory_array.length) {
          alert("Board cleared... generating new board");
          document.getElementById("memory_board").innerHTML = "";
          newBoard();
        }
      } else {
        // if the two flip tiles aren't of the same value
        function flip2Back() {
          // Flip the 2 tiles back over
          var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
          var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
          tile_1.style.background = "orangered";
          tile_1.innerHTML = "";
          tile_2.style.background = "orangered";
          tile_2.innerHTML = "";
          // Clear both arrays
          memory_values = [];
          memory_tile_ids = [];
        }
        setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="memory_board"> </div>
    <script>
        newBoard();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
<style>
    div#memory_board {
        background: #CCC;
        border: #999 1px solid;
        width: 800px;
        height: 540px;
        padding: 24px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    div#memory_board>div {
        background: orangered;
        border: #000 1px solid;
        width: 71px;
        height: 71px;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 64px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Are you actually creating an IMG tag and setting the `src` property to display the image? I can't see that on your code.

Comment: I have an array that will hold the letters which I want to change to hold images.

Comment: Please also learn how to include a [**live** demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: I am new to stack website @Quentin sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new image and set the src value from the array of image. Also set the width and height.

```
var img= new Image();
img.src = val;
img.width="50";
img.height="50";
tile.appendChild(img);
```

See the snippet below:

```css
div#memory_board {
            background: #CCC;
            border: #999 1px solid;
            width: 800px;
            height: 540px;
            padding: 24px;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }

        div#memory_board>div {
            background: orangered;
            border: #000 1px solid;
            width: 71px;
            height: 71px;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 64px;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="memory_board"> </div>
    <script>
    
var memory_array = ["http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/6/1/0/124223379411527084631_Train_(1967-1979).svg.med.png", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/6/1/0/124223379411527084631_Train_(1967-1979).svg.med.png", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/y/T/n/Z/Q/number-2-md.png", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/y/T/n/Z/Q/number-2-md.png", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQo95Lf_9XG0mf3Tb_lfMDUDXiywIdpiiCb5jUSTyOi5ACJXa3C6w", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQo95Lf_9XG0mf3Tb_lfMDUDXiywIdpiiCb5jUSTyOi5ACJXa3C6w", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/K/w/R/r/V/Z/number-4-hi.png", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/K/w/R/r/V/Z/number-4-hi.png"];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;
Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function() {
  var i = this.length,
    j,
    temp;
  while (--i > 0) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = this[j];
    this[j] = this[i];
    this[i] = temp;
  }
};


function newBoard() {
  tiles_flipped = 0;
  var output = "";
  memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
  for (var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++) {
    output +=
      '<div id="tile_' +
      i +
      '" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\'' +
      memory_array[i] +
      "')\"></div>";
  }
  document.getElementById("memory_board").innerHTML = output;
}
function memoryFlipTile(tile, val) {
  //if the title is empty and array = 0  then the rest of code will perform
  if (tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2) {
    //the tile selected will have a white background and the val will be produced
    tile.style.background = "#FFF";
    var img= new Image();
  img.src = val;
    img.width="50";
    img.height="50";
    tile.appendChild(img);
    //if the  array equal = 0
    if (memory_values.length == 0) {
      //push the val and the title id to their respective arrays
      memory_values.push(val);
      memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
      //if the  array equal = 1
    } else if (memory_values.length == 1) {
      //push the val and the title id to their respective arrays
      memory_values.push(val);
      memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
      //if memory_values values are the same
      if (memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]) {
        tiles_flipped += 2;
        // Clear both arrays
        memory_values = [];
        memory_tile_ids = [];
        // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
        if (tiles_flipped == memory_array.length) {
          alert("Board cleared... generating new board");
          document.getElementById("memory_board").innerHTML = "";
          newBoard();
        }
      } else {
        // if the two flip tiles aren't of the same value
        function flip2Back() {
          // Flip the 2 tiles back over
          var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
          var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
          tile_1.style.background = "orangered";
          tile_1.innerHTML = "";
          tile_2.style.background = "orangered";
          tile_2.innerHTML = "";
          // Clear both arrays
          memory_values = [];
          memory_tile_ids = [];
        }
        setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
      }
    }
  }
}

        newBoard();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/g6wue1c0/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't see the difference between a string representing a url, and a string with some text in it. It's both strings. So, in order to display the image, you'd need to do one of the following:

- Create an `<img>` element, and set that elements `src` attribute to the url.
- Add some css to make the element have a `background-image` with the url you have, and style that accordingly.

---

**EDIT**. Let's just do the first method, because it's a bit easier. The following will create an image with the correct source:

```
var imageElement = new Image();
imageElement.src = url;
```

and then we can put it inside an element, for example, putting it inside `tile` would be

```
tile.appendChild(imageElement);
```

---

**EDIT 2**. To transform the array of urls into an array of images, one could simply do this:

```
 // your array of urls
 var url_array = ["./naruto.gif","fakepath/pikachu.gif"];
 // this will create a new array with the same length as url_array
 var memory_array = new Array(url_array.length);
 // loop through it to put the images in memory_array
 for(var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; ++i){
     memory_array[i] = new Image();
     memory_array[i].src = url_array[i];
 }
 // now memory_array contains the right images with source set
```

Comment: how could I go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: how could I have it so the images are placed in an array and then I just loop through it?

Comment: how could I have it so it's in an array instead?

Comment: why do you create a new array? I am kind of confused. Also what is the purpose of `new Image();`

Comment: I create a new array because there's no short way to put the `Image` elements in an array. The `new Image()` is essentially equivalent to `document.createElement('img')` and it creates, well, an image element.